# php - how to determine execution time?

Tags: php, image-processing

I have to process more images with big amount, (10 mb/image)

How do I determine the execution time to process all of the images in queue?

- Determine the time base from the data that we have.
- Set the time limit.
- Run process.

And what do the execution time depend on? (Server, internet speed, type of data...?)

@All: 
i have changed my way to do my issue, send 1reqeust/1image,

so with 40 images, we will be have 40 request. no need to care about excution time :D

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do (what kind of processing, where are the images coming from...) and why do you need to determine the duration beforehand?

Comment: ex: i have create thumb for images. with 30s : we can process 20images 5mb/image. If i have process more than 20 images, i want to know time to process. else processing will be broke :(

Comment: Do you want to calculate an average time for x images?

Comment: How does processing break? Are you hitting the time limit?

Comment: @user603003: we can calculate it before create thumb ?

Comment: @pekka: ex: 40images , when process with image 31th, script break because time limit

Comment: @Chameron: You can run your script 100 times and let it stop the time. So you can calculate an average. You can also try [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: @user: what is set_time_limit depend on ? php version , safe mode, server config  ?

Comment: It depends on safe mode, server (for example Apache defaults to 300s). The function is available in PHP4 and higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test your setup with the code

```
// first image
$start = time();
// ... work on image ...
$elapsed = time() - $start;

if (ini_get('max_execution_time') > $elapsed * $imageCount)
    trigger_warning("may be not able to finish in time", E_USER_WARNING);
```

Please note two things: in the CLI-version of PHP, the max_execution_time is hardcoded to 0 / inifinity (according to [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php#100039)). Also, you may reset the timer by calling [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) again like so:

```
foreach ($imagelist as $image) {
    // ... do image work ....

    // reset timer to 30
    set_time_limit(30);
}
```

That way, you can let your script run forever or at least until you're finished with your image processing. You must enable the appropriate overwrite rules in the apache-configuration to allow this via [`AllowOverride All`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Comment: i have changed my way to do my issue, send 1reqeust/1image, so with 40 images, we will be have 40 request. no need to care about excution time :D

Comment: That's also a way to tackle the problem. =)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest (given your limited info in the question) that you try using the trial and error method - run your process and see how long it takes - increase the time limit until it completes - you might be able to shorten your process.

Comment: what is the best way to track and increase the time limit  ?

Comment: Record the time on `start - $start = time();` then at the end show the time take - `echo time() - $start`. The execution time limit is a php.ini setting

Comment: how to do that when script break. we need to calculate duration before run scriptt

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the server processing time can vary a LOT depending on the current load on the server from other processess. If it's a shared server, some other user can be running some script at this exact time, making your script only perform half as well.

I think it's going to be hard to determine the execution time BEFORE the script is run.

I would upload batches (small groups) of images. The number of images would depend on some testing.

For example, run your script several times simultaneously from different pages to see if they all still complete without breaking. If it works with 5 images in the queue, write your script to process 5 images. After the first five images has processed, store them (write to database or whatever you need), wait a little bit then take the next 5 images.

If it works when you run three scripts with 5 images each at the same time, you should be safe doing it once with whatever some other user on the server is doing.

You change the time execution time limit in the file `php.ini`, or if you don't have access to the file you can set it in on the fly with `set_time_limit(600)` for 600 seconds. I would however write smarter code instead than relying on time limit.

My five cents. Good luck!

Comment: yes, i have try to split images into some requests, not at one big request. But we have a problem is image's amount is not always the same . request 1: 10 images/5mb/image; request 2: 10images/10mb/image

Comment: Then pause the script after a number of bytes transmitted instead of after a specific number of images. For example, after 25 mb is processed, store and pause until taking the next image in queue.